# Can Kurento media server play video from a certain time?

Tags: java, video-streaming, html5-video, kurento

I would like to add tags to a video, and later when I play it back to the user, he or she should be able to start the video from the time bound to the tag. Is it possible?

I checked that the PlayerEndPoint only has a play method that does not accept any time related parameter.

Or is it a client side thing and the media server has nothing to do with playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setPosition(miliseconds)` method to seek forward/backwards in a file playing by a PlayerEndpoint

https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.6.2/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/PlayerEndpoint.html